# What is the percentage?

Tags: percentages

From all the population interviewed 36% respondents had a car at home, 19% had a motorcycle and 4% had both.

I need to find the percentage of respondents having a vehicle either motorcycle or car or both.

Could you please give some hints how to solve this problem ?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look up the [inclusion-exclusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle):

$$P(A\cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A\cap B)$$

Comment: P(A or B) = 0.36+0.19-0.04=0.51(51%) Right ?

Comment: Yep. That's right.

Comment: I had a thought about that and it does not make sence, I need to get percentage for A or B or both. O got only for a or B

Comment: @KostasSt7 Carefully read the linked wikipedia article. The problem is that $P(A)$ also includes those $4\%$ for wich $A$ and $B$ hold at the same time. You want $P(A\cup B) = P(A\setminus B) + P(B\setminus A) + P(A\cap B)$ where $A\setminus B$ denotes set difference ($A$ but not $B$).

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @KostasSt7 After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/)